# Getting InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Path '%s' from root %s must not span a cyclic property reference when using ExampleMatcher

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

**Client Model:**

```java
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private ClientLegalTerm clientLegalTerm;

    ...//Getters and Setters
}
```

**ClientLegalTerm model:**

```java
@Entity
public class ClientLegalTerm {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_client_legal_term_client_id"))
    private Client client;

    ...//Getters and Setters
}
```

**MyNewEntity model:**

```java
@Entity
public class MyNewEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Client client;

    ...//Getters and Setters
```

I'm using `JpaRepository` to manage `MyNewEntity` and I want to use QueryByExample to get an instance from the repo.

```java
    ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
           .withMatcher("client.id", match -> match.exact());
    Example<MyNewEntity> example = Example.of(new MyNewEntity(client), matcher);

    Optional<MyNewEntity> optionalEntity = investorClosedEndTransactionRepository.findOne(example);
```

But I'm getting an exception on the `findOne()` call if the ClientLegalTerm is populated.
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Path 'client.legalTerm.client' from root MyNewEntity must not span a cyclic property reference!`
I know it's because there is a circular reference back to the same client from within client, but because ClientLegalTerm is a One to One table, and that's the model I am dealing with. Is there a way to get around that exception?

Maybe there a different way to match the client by just its Id?

**Full Stacktrace:**

```
2020-11-04 12:28:17,588 ERROR [com.krfs.web.handler.ControllerExceptionHandler handleUncaughtException] - 127.0.0.1 8de1b613-6e6d-4d00-82b3-773934d9f09d An unhandled exception has occurred
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Path 'client.legalTerm.client' from root InvestorClosedEndTransaction must not span a cyclic property reference!
[{ com.alpsinc.live.loader.InvestorClosedEndTransaction@c0c64c52 }] -client-> [{ com.krfs.model.Client@86d }] -legalTerm-> [{ com.krfs.model.ClientLegalTerm@86d }] -client-> [{ com.krfs.model.Client@86d }]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.getPredicates(QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.java:163)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.getPredicates(QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.java:167)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.getPredicates(QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.java:167)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.getPredicate(QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.java:102)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository$ExampleSpecification.toPredicate(SimpleJpaRepository.java:886)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.applySpecificationToCriteria(SimpleJpaRepository.java:762)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:693)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findOne(SimpleJpaRepository.java:466)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6222.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45005)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2110.findOne(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6220.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45005)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.util.ReloadingProxyFactory$ReloadingMethodHandler.invoke(SourceFile:74)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2110.findOne(Unknown Source)
        at com.alpsinc.live.loader.InvestorClosedEndTransactionService.validateEntityStatus(InvestorClosedEndTransactionService.java:78)
```

Comment: Can you post the complete StackTrace?

Comment: @TechGeek49 Added.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Path 'company.taxData.company' from root User must not span a cyclic property reference!
```

In my case was because I had these models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Item
{
    @NotBlank
    @Email
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Company company;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Company extends Item
{
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<User> users;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Address> addresses;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Address extends Item
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Company company;
}
```

And I was trying to get the user in this way:

```
public Optional<User> findOneByEmailAndCompany(final String email, final Company company)
{
    final User user = new User();
    user.setCompany(company);
    user.setEmail(email);
    return userRepository.findOne(Example.of(user));
}
```

And the `QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder` JPA class tries to resolve in a reflection way the attributes and classes, but in `spansCycle` function checks that the `identityHex` of the actual `value` and the `identityHex` of the `parent` are the same and throws the `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` to avoid an infinite recursión:

```
boolean spansCycle() {

    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    }

    String identityHex = ObjectUtils.getIdentityHexString(value);
    PathNode current = parent;

    while (current != null) {

        if (current.value != null && ObjectUtils.getIdentityHexString(current.value).equals(identityHex)) {
            return true;
        }
        current = current.parent;
    }

return false;
}
```

I solved that by creating a custom query in the UserRepository doing the Inner join between Company and User:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
{
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u INNER JOIN u.company uc WHERE uc.id = :companyId AND u.email = :userEmail")
    public Optional<User> findByEmailAndCompanyId(String userEmail, Long companyId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work for me as well, but I wanted to know if there is a way around it with ExampleMatcher?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think not, because the idea of that exception is to avoid an infinite recursion caused by the `QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder` class, which tries to resolve the `ExampleMatcher` in a reflective way :/